# How to save a pandas dataframe such that there is no delimiter?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (6,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  1
1  1  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  1  1
4  0  1  1
5  1  1  1
```

Let's say I take the transpose and wish to save it

```
df = df.T

   0  1  2  3  4  5
X  1  1  0  0  0  1
Y  0  1  0  1  1  1
Z  1  0  0  1  1  1
```

So, there three rows. I would like to save it in this format:

```
X  110001
Y  010111
Z  100111
```

I tried

```
df.to_csv("filename.txt", header=None, index=None, sep='')
```

However, this outputs an error:

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

Is it possible to save the dataframe in this manner, or is there some what to combine all columns into one? What is the most "pandas" solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave original `df` alone.  Don't transpose.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (6,3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

df.astype(str).apply(''.join)

X    101100
Y    101001
Z    111110
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to transpose, then you can do something like this:

```
In [126]: df.T.apply(lambda row: ''.join(map(str, row)), axis=1)
Out[126]: 
X    001111
Y    000000
Z    010010
dtype: object
```